# Change menu link url to #

Tags: jquery

the code below works correctly (changes first anchor url to #) with first dropdown-menu, but not with second one:

```
if($(window).width() >= 1000){
$('#main-menu li:has(.dropdown-menu)').hover(function (event) {
if ($(event.target).parents('.dropdown-menu').length > 0) {
    event.stopPropagation();      
} else {
  $(this).find('a:first').attr('href','#');
   event.preventDefault();
} 
});
}
```

outputs:

```
<ul id="main-menu">
<li><a href="#">Uudised</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="https://eoy.ee/oosorr/uudised/?c=sorri-aasta-uudised">Sorri aasta uudised</a></li>
<li><a href="https://eoy.ee/oosorr/uudised/?c=teadusuudised">Teadusuudised</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="https://eoy.ee/oosorr/uudised/?c=content">Content</a></li>
<li><a href="https://eoy.ee/oosorr/uudised/?c=site-design">Site design</a</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

but i would like:

```
<ul id="main-menu">
<li><a href="#">Uudised</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="https://eoy.ee/oosorr/uudised/?c=sorri-aasta-uudised">Sorri aasta uudised</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Teadusuudised</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="https://eoy.ee/oosorr/uudised/?c=content">Content</a></li>
<li><a href="https://eoy.ee/oosorr/uudised/?c=site-design">Site design</a</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

tried this, but not working:

```
   $('#main-menu li:has(.dropdown-menu),#main-menu > li > ul > li:has(.dropdown-menu)').hover(function (event) {....
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using $(this).find('a:first') which finds the first a element in the list. Try to remove the ':first' from it and see if it helps.

Comment: ...actually it's working, but it affects all links in dropdown menu. my bad